# Python docstrings broken, requires parameter first

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring, autodoc

I got a strange error using python's docstrings in combination with Sphinx Autodoc/Napoleon:

When using docstrings, the formatting is broken as soon as i put the comment *above* the parameters.

```
"""
This yields in a wrongly formatted doc page.
:param chronic:
:type chronic:
"""
```

When i put the text after the parameters (contrary to pythons build in doc-string generation format), it works:

```
"""
:param chronic:
:type chronic:
The prints the doc string just fine.
"""
```

(See screenshots for results).
Whats the cause of this strange formatting error?

Repaired:

[image: repaired]

Broken:

[image: broken]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two blocks of text in the first example:

1. The "This yields in a wrongly formatted doc page." summary line.
2. The [info field list](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#info-field-lists).

The summary line should be the first thing in a docstring and it should be followed by a blank line (see https://peps.python.org/pep-0257). So just add a blank line.

```
"""
This yields a nicely formatted doc page.

:param chronic: description of chronic
:type chronic: list
"""
```

Comment: Ah, crazy, that's it, the empty line..