# Python Sphinx inheritance path display and view configuration

Tags: python, python-3.x, documentation, python-sphinx

I'm trying to generate a project documentation with Sphinx. Here is my project tree:

```
project_folder
   docs
   package_0
      __init__.py
      script_0.py
      package_1
         __init__.py
         package_2
            script_2.py
         package_3
            script_3.py
            script_33.py
         package_4
            script_4.py
            script_44.py
```

I execute `sphinx-quickstart` with `Separate source and build directories?: No` flag in `/docs` folder.
Than I add some edits in code in the `/docs/conf.py`:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))


project = 'RC API'
copyright = '2024, Mike'
author = 'Mike'
release = '1.0.0'

extensions = ['sphinx.ext.todo', 'sphinx.ext.viewcode', 'sphinx.ext.autodoc']

templates_path = ['_templates']
exclude_patterns = ['_build', 'Thumbs.db', '.DS_Store']

language = 'en'

html_theme = 'alabaster'
html_static_path = ['_static']
```

In `/docs/index.rst` I add `modules` under the `toctree`. The file looks like this:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

   modules


* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

After that I execute `sphinx-apidoc -o docs package_0` in the `/project_folder`. This causes `rst` files generation in `/docs` folder.

Finally I run `make html` in `/docs` folder. All docs are done.

**Here is the questions**:
How to shorten the inheritance path of every method/class? We already in the package, so there is no reason to write full method/class path inside the package. Here is the example:
`Here some scripts and functions inside the packages (and what i want to do with them).`
[image]

This style is overloaded with information. Is it possible to make structure looks like the project tree in IDE? With no additional information (telling "this is the package" and "this is the module") and no long inheritance paths?
And one more question: How should I setup the functions docstring parsing to avoid compressing all text in a single row? Example:
[image]

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: @mzjn, sure. I just thought that it would be a bad practice to decompose two questions from the same logical group to different posts.

Comment: The result you get in the example is based on the default output from `sphinx-apidoc`. That output can be customized by modifying the templates, which should help with at least some of your issues. See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html and https://stackoverflow.com/a/57520238/407651.

Comment: The problem with text appearing unformatted on a single row is probably caused by a missing blank line in the docstring. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73998836/407651

Comment: @mzjn, thank you for the answers. Blank line problem has been solved. About apidoc: May be I've understood the docs wrong and choose wrong option, but `docs>sphinx-apidoc --no-headings -o docs package_0` doesn't have effect for me.

Comment: If you need help with sphinx-apidoc and templates, please ask a new question. Another option is to edit the output from sphinx-apidoc by hand and then save those files. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28481785/407651.

Comment: `--no-headings` has no effect for me either. Can't explain it. Feels like a bug...